# If else with Ternary operator

Tags: php, operators, ternary

Below is the example:
If I write like:

```
<?php
$var = 'A';
echo    ($var == 'B' || $var == 'C')  ? 'B or C' : 'A';
?>
```

//Out will be "A"
But if I write like below:

```
<?php
$var = 'A';
echo    ($var == ('B' || 'C'))  ? 'B or C' : 'A';
?>
```

It give me out put as "B or C".
Here ($var == ('B' || 'C')) is not correct or i am missing something?

Created PHP fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wju-46r

Comment: Because in the second you're doing an OR of 'B' and 'C', then comparing the result of that with $var; 'B' OR 'C' will evaluate to a Boolean (true), so you get type casting $var to Boolean to compare with Boolean true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has no relation to ternary operator. It's about [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and comparison.

In second case, you're doing `'B' || 'C'` which will be treated as `true` - since `||` is *logical* operator. So `'A' == true` is true because of type juggling, thus `B or C` will be your result

Answer (score 0):

echo    ($var === ('B' || 'C'))  ? 'B or C' : 'A';

This is the right answer you must have to check data type also.

Comment: this will not work if you give $var = 'B'... it will give you 'A'